# Passing CSS list of colors to JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have portlet witch prints some chart and these colors represent colors of lines in graph. I have 3 - 4 sites and every site has different CSS and i need make these colors depend on CSS specific site.

I have something like this

```
var options = {
    colors: ["#0099cc", "#f7a35c", "#ff0066",
            "#90ee7e", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee",
            "#7cb5ec", "#eeaaee", "#55bf3b",
            "#df5353", "#7798bf", "#aaeeee"]
}
```

and i need find some elegant way how to get these colors values from CSS.

Simplified, i need this

**CSS file**

```
.colors {
 ?????
}
```

**JS file**

```
options.colors = loadColorsFromCSS();
```

Comment: you mean like [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)?

Comment: yea something like this, but i need for example 10 colors and idk, how to represent it in CSS. Make class for each color scares me..

Comment: Please first of all properly describe what you want to _achieve_ here.

Comment: so you just want to pull all the arbitrary colors from the css file or what? doesn't it matter whether they're background colors or border colors or something else? i don't get it...

Comment: Is the CSS in a file or in the DOM?

Comment: I have portlet witch prints some chart and these colors represent colors of lines in graph. I have 3 - 4 sites and every site has different CSS and i need make these colors depend on CSS specific site.

Comment: Are all the colours 'hex' colours? or do you also need rbg, hsl, etc.?

Comment: just hex values, but it doesn't matter, i can convert it in JS

Answer (score 0):

Basically as CSS is a file which should be somewhere in server so you can not directly read content of CSS file directly via JS. So there are **two ways** to achieve what you want.

**1st:**

Use CSS in HTML file.
e.g,

```
<style id="stylesheet">
.color{}
</style>
```

Now in JS,

```
cssContent = document.getElementById("stylesheet").innerHtml;

//Now do whatever you want with cssContent
```

**2nd:**

Use ajax to bring content of CSS file from server and do whatever you want with that.

**Now next issue is how to parse CSS from CSS content easily:**

There is no direct way to parse CSS via JS, either you have to write your own implementation or use some already existing library like "JSCSSP"

Comment: There is **inline CSS** which is not in a file outside in server.

Comment: @TahaPaksu he wrote clearly CSS file and he never mentioned anywhere that style is inline. Plus I have mentioned processes for all kind of possibilities.

Comment: I'm writing the comment to your *CSS is a file which should be somewhere in server* assumption. This is not correct.

Comment: Ok. Then you can check the 1st option I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is my attempt:
This will find all the colours in a CSS file.

```
(async function () {
    // Get the CSS from a file
    const css = await fetch('file.css')
    // Convert the file to text
    .then(response => response.text())
    // Remove the comments
    .then(text => text.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//g, ''));

    // Process the css text.
    const colours = [];

    // Find hex colours
    // #123456 or #123
    (css.match(/(#[\da-f]{6}|#[\da-f]{3})/g) || [])

    // Add them to the colours array
    .forEach(colour => colours.push(colour));


    // Find rgb(a) and hsl(a) colours
    // rgb(25, 255, 53) or rgbs(25, 255, 53, 0)
    // hsl(180, 50%, 50%) or hsls(180, 50%, 50%, 0)
    (css.match(/(rgb|hsl)(a?)\(([\d\.\-\s,]{5,})\)/g) || [])

    // Add them to the colours array
    .forEach(colour => colours.push(colour));

    // Find named colours 
    const colourList = [
        'Black', 'Navy', 'DarkBlue', 'MediumBlue', 'Blue', 'DarkGreen', 'Green', 'Teal',
        'DarkCyan', 'DeepSkyBlue', 'DarkTurquoise', 'MediumSpringGreen', 'Lime', 'SpringGreen',
        'Aqua', 'Cyan', 'MidnightBlue', 'DodgerBlue', 'LightSeaGreen', 'ForestGreen', 'SeaGreen',
        'DarkSlateGray', 'DarkSlateGrey', 'LimeGreen', 'MediumSeaGreen', 'Turquoise', 'RoyalBlue',
        'SteelBlue', 'DarkSlateBlue', 'MediumTurquoise', 'Indigo', 'DarkOliveGreen', 'CadetBlue',
        'CornflowerBlue', 'RebeccaPurple', 'MediumAquaMarine', 'DimGray', 'DimGrey', 'SlateBlue',
        'OliveDrab', 'SlateGray', 'SlateGrey', 'LightSlateGray', 'LightSlateGrey', 'MediumSlateBlue',
        'LawnGreen', 'Chartreuse', 'Aquamarine', 'Maroon', 'Purple', 'Olive', 'Gray', 'Grey', 'SkyBlue',
        'LightSkyBlue', 'BlueViolet', 'DarkRed', 'DarkMagenta', 'SaddleBrown', 'DarkSeaGreen', 'LightGreen',
        'MediumPurple', 'DarkViolet', 'PaleGreen', 'DarkOrchid', 'YellowGreen', 'Sienna', 'Brown', 'DarkGray',
        'DarkGrey', 'LightBlue', 'GreenYellow', 'PaleTurquoise', 'LightSteelBlue', 'PowderBlue', 'FireBrick',
        'DarkGoldenRod', 'MediumOrchid', 'RosyBrown', 'DarkKhaki', 'Silver', 'MediumVioletRed', 'IndianRed',
        'Peru', 'Chocolate', 'Tan', 'LightGray', 'LightGrey', 'Thistle', 'Orchid', 'GoldenRod', 'PaleVioletRed',
        'Crimson', 'Gainsboro', 'Plum', 'BurlyWood', 'LightCyan', 'Lavender', 'DarkSalmon', 'Violet',
        'PaleGoldenRod', 'LightCoral', 'Khaki', 'AliceBlue', 'HoneyDew', 'Azure', 'SandyBrown', 'Wheat',
        'Beige', 'WhiteSmoke', 'MintCream', 'GhostWhite', 'Salmon', 'AntiqueWhite', 'Linen', 'LightGoldenRodYellow',
        'OldLace', 'Red', 'Fuchsia', 'Magenta', 'DeepPink', 'OrangeRed', 'Tomato', 'HotPink', 'Coral', 'DarkOrange',
        'LightSalmon', 'Orange', 'LightPink', 'Pink', 'Gold', 'PeachPuff', 'NavajoWhite', 'Moccasin', 'Bisque',
        'MistyRose', 'BlanchedAlmond', 'PapayaWhip', 'LavenderBlush', 'SeaShell', 'Cornsilk', 'LemonChiffon',
        'FloralWhite', 'Snow', 'Yellow', 'LightYellow', 'Ivory', 'White'
    ];

    (css.match(new RegExp(colourList.join('|'), 'g')) || [])
    // Add them to the colours array
    .forEach(colour => colours.push(colour));

    // Here 'should' be all the colours
    // The filter removes all the duplicate colours
    console.log(colours.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i));
})();
```

It is very important to note that this is NOT the best way of doing this, and it is not fool proof. A better way in my opinion would be a CSS parser, for example https://github.com/reworkcss/css, then parsing that in some way.

However, this is a mute point because I believe that you should set the colours manually on a per site basis, instead of trying to parse the colours.